# How to exclude only *.spec files and include all other *.js files under a directory in grunt task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I need to include all `*.js` files and exclude only `*.spec.js` files under a directory.

I tried the following ways, it's either including all js or excluding all js files

`'built/code/js/libs/preact/**/!(*.spec).js')`  but it fails with the message syntax error near unexpected token `('.

If I do this way - `'built/code/js/libs/preact/**/!*.spec.js')`  it excludes all js files

If I add in 2 different lines like below it excludes all js files

```
('built/code/js/libs/preact/**/*.js' +
'built/code/js/libs/preact/**/!*.spec.js')
```

Please let me know if there's a way to exclude spec files and include all other js files.

Comment: Can you try this line: '!built/code/js/libs/preact/**/*.spec.js'?

Comment: I tried this, it excludes all js files @MaikLowrey